# Failed to connect to queue manager 'QUEUE-NAME' with connection mode 'Client' and host

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-camel, ibm-mq, jms-topic

I have developed subscripe (topic) conncept using Camel. it is working fine in my local tomcat.but it is not working in my test environment tomcat. it is  getting below mentioned error. kindly help me to resolve the issue and how to debug the issue.

is it related to server configuration ?

**Error**

```
    org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessageListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful
     SEVERE: Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TOPIC-NAME' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to
 connect to queue manager 'QUEUE-MANAGER' with connection mode 'Client' and
 host name 'HOST-NAME'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException:
 JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED')
 reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

regards,
Gnana

Comment: That error reports TOPIC-NAME is that really the name of the topic to use? Or is it some value that has not been replaced to the actual value?

Comment: TOPIC-NAME  dummy value. I should not share actual topic name.

Comment: Did you try any of the diagnostics I mentioned in my answer?  What happened when you did?

Answer (score 5):

There is almost no information to go on here and therefore no way to answer with any confidence.  Instead, I'll provide a diagnostic process and hopefully you will find the problem.  Note that in the future if you have similar issues, it would help to list the diagnostics you have already tried so that people responding can narrow down their answers.

In order for this to work, the QMgr must be running a listener, have a channel defined and available, have authorizations set up to allow the connection, and be able to resolve the queue or topic requested.  With that in mind, the things I normally check and the order I check them in is as follows:

1. Is the QMgr running.
2. Is the listener running?  On what port?
3. Can I telnet to the QMgr on the listener port?  i.e. `telnet mqhost 1414`.
4. Is the channel defined? If so, is it available?
5. Do the sample client programs work? In this case, [`amqspubc`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024230_.htm?lang=en) is the one to try.

There are other considerations and if all of the above work, it is time to look into the client code and configuration, the versions of the client and server, authorizations, etc.  But until you know that the basic configuration is in place to support a client connection (which was not indicated in the question) then these are the things to start with.

Comment: I have verified that I am able to connect the mqhost using telnet command

Comment: port and other details are correct. it is working fine in my local machine.same code is not working in testing environment

Comment: yes we are able to connect. we suspect that it is environment issue. how to prove that it is environement issue.

Comment: Depends on the version.  Can you update the question with the output of `dspmqver -a` on the client application node and the QMgr node?

Comment: Hey @T.Rob
I tried your diagnostics. Mine is failing at step number 3, I'm getting operation timed out even when I run my client against the MQ I'm getting the same JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

The root of this being aused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

What should I do?

Comment: If the listener is running and you can't telnet to it, then there isn't an IP path to the QMgr.  Check for issues with IP Tables, host-based firewall, network routing issues, etc.